# having issue creating proxy server application

Tags: python

I am having issue creating proxy(tcp) in socket programming using python who communicate between client/server to send messages. The problem is as follow: 
I want to create client, proxy and server python application where clients can only communicate with proxy, and proxy communicate with server. 
Each client sends a number to the proxy, and waits for the answer. After the
answer they close the connection.
The proxy waits for a fixed N number of clients to send a number to it. When
N is reached, the proxy sends the received numbers to the server (followed by the END string), and waits for an answer from it. After it receives an answer from the server, the proxy sends it back to all of the clients. After this point, the proxy can close the communication.

The server receives from the proxy the N numbers, and after it, the END string,
which indicates, that the proxy will not send any other messages to the server.
The server calculates the average, and sends it to the proxy. After this point, it can close the connection.

Do I need to create 2 socket object on proxy(one for client, one for server). Please input your thought, how can I write program for client, server and proxy??

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very general. Try to write some code first, and then if you have a specific problem you could ask about it here

Comment: I am very new to python. So, I can write client/server. But I dont know how to write client/server with proxy using select function.

Comment: just try searching google, there are many answered questions and guides out there - https://encrypted.google.com/#q=writing%20proxy%20server%20python&safe=off

Comment: I tried this anyway already. if there are 4 client who send number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by end then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg:: 10) to proxy and then to client by proxy.

Comment: so edit your question to be more specific, show the code that doesn't work as expected and explain the error

Comment: sorry, I dont knw how to implement logic which is mentioned.thats why I have posted this here to know. I had just given example (4 clients) to provide more clear understanding. Exp:- if there are 4 different clients who send number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by END then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg:10+10+10+10 /4 = 10) to proxy and then proxy send this average msg to client..... I dont know how to create logic for this kind of messages from client to proxy and from proxy to server

Comment: What kind of logic? You mean like, what sockets you should use?

Comment: I am using TCP socket here. Just wanted to know how can I create connection between client, proxy and server application using TCP. and how to send numbers(integer value) to proxy application... sorry for confusion but I explained in details above.

Comment: Ok, this is clearer. Your original question has too many details...

Answer (score 0):

You have to create one socket that connects between the client and the proxy, and one socket that connects between proxy and the server.

Sockets can transfer only raw bytes, so you have to convert your numbers to strings in a way you choose. You don't have to send an end signal. Instead just send all your numbers at once. You can use pickle module to convert an array of numbers to a string, send it and then converted to back, or just use your own method of stringifying and then converting to numbers again.

Comment: Please check , I have created connections but dont know how to send numbers from clients to proxy/server and then from server to proxy to client after calculation average by server. Please see code and advise

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your valuable input. Here is the code which I have created. Please check and let me know How can I implement using SELECT...
For client::::

```
import socket
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21001
proxysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxysock.connect((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
      x = int(raw_input())
      proxysock.sendall(x)
      data = proxysock.recv(1024)
      proxysock.close()
```

For Proxy::

```
   import socket
   from thread import *
   HOST = 'localhost'
   PORT = 21001
   max_conn = 5
   buffer_size = 2048

def start():

proxyserversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxyserversock.bind((HOST, PORT))
proxyserversock.listen(max_conn)

while 1:
    client_sock, addr = proxyserversock.accept()
    data = client_sock.recv(buffer_size)


    serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    serversock.sendall(X)
    serversock.recv(buffer_size)
    client_sock.sendall()
    serversock.close()  
    client_sock.close()
```

**For Server::**

```
   import socket 
   HOST = 'localhost'
   PORT = 21001


 serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 serversock.bind((HOST, PORT))
 s.listen(10) 
 while 1:
       proxyclientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
data = proxyclientsock.recv(2048) 

proxyclientsock.sendall()
proxyclientsock.close()
```

I have written code to connect client with proxy and proxy with client. Please input your thought, how can N number of client(e.g., 4 clients) can send integer number to proxy? and proxy send them to server. I want to implement code as per below:
if there are 4 client who send number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by END then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg = 10+10+10+10/4 = 10) to proxy and then proxy sent back average result to client.

I understand what you replied before but not able to implement in code (using SELECT). Please see code and edit them. I would really appreciate. Thanks.

Comment: You should ask this as a new question, not as an answer :)

Comment: I have asked this as new question. Please check and suggest.

Comment: I have asked this as new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044000/creating-proxy-sending-messages-through-proxy-application