# creating proxy, sending messages through proxy application

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am having issue how to send numbers from N client to proxy. Proxy forward numbers from clients to server. Server calculate average and send back to proxy and then finally client gets reply from proxy.

I am using below **TCP socket (using Python)**.  I am trying to do as follow::
if there are 4 client who send integer number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by END then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg = 10+10+10+10/4 = 10) to proxy and then proxy sent back average result to client.

I have created connection between client/proxy/server, however i am having issue with sending integer numbers using SELECT.

Please check the below code and advise how can I implement this using SELECT (in Python TCP socket).

For client::::

```
import socket
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21001
proxysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxysock.connect((HOST, PORT))
while 1:
      x = int(raw_input())
      proxysock.sendall(x)
      data = proxysock.recv(1024)
      proxysock.close()
```

For Proxy::

```
   import socket
   from thread import *
   HOST = 'localhost'
   PORT = 21001
   max_conn = 5
   buffer_size = 2048

def start():

proxyserversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
proxyserversock.bind((HOST, PORT))
proxyserversock.listen(max_conn)

while 1:
    client_sock, addr = proxyserversock.accept()
    data = client_sock.recv(buffer_size)


    serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.connect((HOST, PORT))
    serversock.sendall(X)
    serversock.recv(buffer_size)
    client_sock.sendall()
    serversock.close()  
    client_sock.close()
```

**For Server::**

```
   import socket 
   HOST = 'localhost'
   PORT = 21001


 serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 serversock.bind((HOST, PORT))
 s.listen(10) 
 while 1:
       proxyclientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
data = proxyclientsock.recv(2048) 

proxyclientsock.sendall()
proxyclientsock.close()
```

Comment: What are the issues you are having? why do you need select?

Comment: As part of my assignment, I need to use select. Requirement is: if there are 4 client who send integer number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by END then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg = 10+10+10+10/4 = 10) to proxy and then proxy sent back average result to client.

Comment: You said you had issues with your code. What are the problems?

Comment: I have only created connection between client, proxy and server. I have not created code to send numbers between them. I want to add code in above mentioned Client/proxy/server application.  Please tell me how to implement this requirement in above code using SELECT ::-  if there are 4 client who send integer number like 10, 10,10,10 to proxy followed by END then proxy receive them as {10,10,10,10, end} and send to server. and server reply back after calculating average (e.g;, avg = 10+10+10+10/4 = 10) to proxy and then proxy sent back average result to client.

Comment: Try to search Google for ways to do that and read documentations. Then create some initial code. If you get stuck in the middle, feel free to ask about the problem.

Comment: I have  written code and searched , I got stuck here. so I had posted here for help. Anyway. thank you. I wrote same thing many times here.

Comment: It's hard to help, if you don't explain what is the problem with your code. In this website you don't ask for people to write code for you, but help you understand problems in your own code. You are saying you have issues. What are they? An exception? Unexpected behavior?

Comment: The "requirement" that you stated three times does not contain a mention of SELECT. If the use of some SELECT is really part of the "requirement", you have not stated the full "requirement". Moreover, from your "requirement" it is unclear whether each of the 4 clients sends one _10_ or all _10,10,10,10, END_.